# Is it possible to show a WPF Application on a html file in my Nodejs application

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, wpf, edgejs

A few friends of mine and me started to work on a school project, which mainly focuses on Speech Analysis. They wanted to make an application in WPF and I tried to do the Analysis in different programming languages. Mainly C#, Python and JavaScript. I found the perfect way to analyze the Speech-Input in a way we wanted it, but the Programm is written in JavaScript, running in a Nodejs Server.

I searched for a way to implement the Nodejs Server in C# but had some difficulties, so I looked around and found EdgeJs which works the other way around. 
Basically making it possible work with .Net and C# Code in JavaScript.

All I really need to do is call functions from my Nodejs application within the C# Code.

The problem is, I have no idea how to get a whole WPF application into the NodejS application, i only found examples with console applications.

Would really aprreciate your input and maybe you know a way to solve my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of making a Webservice for your C# application and then calling your C# functions using Node and AJAX via the webservice

Comment: Sorry for my bad phrasing.I meant so say, that I need to call the JavaScript functions from the C# Application.

The WPF Application is the User interface for the Analysis and other Features and the JavaScript has the functionallity for the Speech Analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the input/output you're looking for, you could add some Restful Web Api endpoints to your Node application/server. These rest endpoints will call the speech-analysis functions internally, and then return the results.

If you run your WPF app on the same machine as your node server, you should be able to easily make calls to the API and get the results you are looking for.

Comment: How can I make a rest call from another program that is running on the same machine? I have never done this before.

Comment: The Node server would be accessible via HTTP request to your localhost.
You could use WebClient in your WPF app to make the requests to your locally hosted node server.

I believe it's simple to get started with a Rest API in Node with Express. 

These two topics and little bit of research should get you where you want to be.

Ideally if you're developing a WPF app, you'd want an .Net lib to do the speech analysis - that's the correct way to do it. 

The way I've mentioned is a bit of a hack, but if you're determined to use the JS libs then it's probably your fastest route.